# When importing a file (such as a CSV file) on an iPhone, can the views be changed

Tags: objective-c, ios, import

I am trying to create an app in which you can import a file. It is set up on a storyboard with the iOS deployment target of 5.1. The tabbar is already set up with the storyboard.

I would like to change the view such that when the user has a file that they wish to import (from an e-mail for example), the app switches the view to another page on the tab bar.

When I tried to set this up, inside the `viewDidLoad` on the initial page of the tab bar, it does not work as that function does not get read.

What should I do?

Should I change the AppDelegate in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method? If so, does the `applicationDidBecomeActive` get read before or after `application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation` method?

Should I change the initial page's code? If so, what gets called when I import the file?

Here's some of the code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

...

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        [self handleOpenURL:url];        
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSError *outError;
    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                       error:&outError];
    file = fileString;
}
```

Comment: What is the code that is not working? Also can you show the error log.

Comment: I've put up some of my AppDelegate code. I don't get an error, the app just goes to the initial page when I import a file.

Answer (score 0):

to perform page change call in the open file method

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
//Initiates the segue with the specified identifier from the view controller’s storyboard file.
```